# C# Execute CMD command without admin rights

Tags: cmd, command, admin, administrator, rights

i need that my program to start a command on cmd without the need to have administrator rights, the command to run should be this:
"aka.exe 84920"
 it's possible?
I also tried with a .bat file but to start another process the program must be started with administrator rights
Thanks

Comment: If `aka.exe` requires Administrator privilege, then it will need to exist. Have you tried `RUNAS`? If UAC is enabled, there may be a UI to which a response is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a process without admin rights, in c# like this:

using System.Diagnostics;

```
Process.Start("aka.exe 84920");
```

A minute ago I opened a Console Application and put this on the main method:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

It works!! Without admin rights